# invalid file error when using a thumbnail with link posts when posting using php SDK

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to upload a custom thumbnail with a link post using the php sdk but it is showing the error

**(#100)Invalid File. Expected file of one of the following types: image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png**

the uploaded file works ok for posting a photo so I know the file is ok, what could be the issue here when trying to post as a link?

on this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/link_post_custom_image/

it shows it should work. I've tried ignoring the uploaded file and hard code a path to a known existing image but it still shows the error when trying to post a link with the 'thumbnail' parameter

I've tried copying the file to local first and then using that path but still it shows the error

if I leave off the thumbnail and picture parameters, facebook grabs it's own image for the thumbnail so the posting function works, just not with the thumbnail parameter

here is a sample bit of code
**the html form**

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="newpost.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="fbpages">
                <?php
                foreach($c->accounts as $page){
                    echo '<li title="Post to '.$page->name.'" class="fbpage" pageid="'.$page->id.'"><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'.$page->id.'/picture" width="37" height="37"/></li>';
                }
                echo '<li title="post to personal timeline" class="fbpage" pageid="personal"><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'.$user.'/picture" width="37" height="37"/></li>';
                echo '<li title="Post to Wordpress" class="fbpage" pageid="wordpress"><img src="images/wordpress-logo.png"/></li>';
                ?>  
                <input type="hidden" name="fbpages" />          
            </div>
            <div id="fields">
                <div id="text-1">
                    <textarea id="message" name="message"><?php if($c->alt){ echo $c->alt;}?></textarea>
                </div>
                <div id="image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $c->src;?>" />
                    <br><input name="nopicture" value="yes" type="checkbox"/>No Picture (let facebook choose)
                    <input type="file" name="file"/>
                </div>
                <div id="text-2">
                    <p>Name<br><input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" value="<?php echo $c->title;?>"/></p>
                    <p>Link<br><input type="text" id="link" name="link" placeholder="link" value="<?php echo $c->foundpage;?>"/></p>
                    <?php $da = parse_url($c->foundpage); $caption = $da['host'];   ?>
                    <p>Caption<br><input type="text" id="caption" name="caption" placeholder="caption" value="<?php echo $caption;?>"/></p>
                    <p>Description<br><textarea id="description" name="description" placeholder="description"><?php echo $c->description ? $c->description : $c->alt;?></textarea></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="controls">
                <div id="leftcontrols">
                    <p><strong>Auto Comment</strong><p>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="docomment" name="docomment" value="yes" />
                        <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="3" placeholder="Comment text"><?php echo 'Found at '.$c->foundpage;?></textarea>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="rightcontrols">
                    <strong>Select type of post:</strong><br />
                    <select id="type" name="type">
                        <option value="photo">Post a Photo</option>
                        <option value="link">Post a Link</option>
                        <option value="status">Post a Status</option>
                    </select>
                    <p class="controls">
                        <strong>Time and Date to post</strong><br />
                            <input type="text" id="date" name="date" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i');?>" placeholder="date"/>
                            <br><button id="now">Now</button> <button id="plus6">+6 Hours</button>
                        </div>
                    </p>
                    <input type="submit" name="clear" value="clear"/>
                    <p id="submit">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the function that posts as a photo that works fine

```
if(!empty($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])){
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
    $c['image'] = '@'.$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
if($type == 'photo'){
    // build args
    $args = array(
        'message' => $message,
        'published'=>$scheduledpost ? 0 : 1,
        'no_story' => 0,
        'access_token' => $accesstoken
    );
    if(isset($c['image'])){
        $args['image'] = $c['image'];
    } else {
        $args['url'] = $c['src'];
    }
    if($scheduledpost){
        $args['scheduled_publish_time'] = $timetopost;
    } 

    try {
        $photo = $facebook->api($pageid . '/photos', 'post', $args);
        // post comment if sent
        if( is_array( $photo ) && !empty( $photo['id'] ) ){
            ///photo posted, make comment with link
            if(isset($_POST['docomment']) && $_POST['docomment'] == 'yes'){
                $commentmessage = 'Found at '.$_POST['comment'];
                try{
                    $comment = $facebook ->api('/'.$photo['id'].'/comments', 
                        'post', 
                        array(
                            'access_token' => $accesstoken,
                            'message' => $commentmessage,
                        )
                    );
                } catch (FacebookApiException $e){
                    echo '<h2>Had an error updating the comment '.$e->getMessage();
                }
            }

        }
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        echo "<h2>Error</h2>can't post photo. It must be protected from being shared. <script>setTimeout(\"self.close();\",2500);</script>";
        exit;
    }
```

but when I try to post a link using the same uploaded file , it shows the error

```
if($type == 'link'){
    //debugbreak();

    $args = array(
        'access_token' => $accesstoken,
        'message' => $message,
        'name' => $_REQUEST['name'],
        'link' => $_REQUEST['link'],
        'caption'=>$_REQUEST['caption'],
        'description' => $_REQUEST['description'],
        'picture'=> $c['src'],
        'published'=> 1
    );
    if(isset($_POST['nopicture'])){
        unset($args['picture']);
    }
    if(isset($c['image'])){
        $args['thumbnail'] = $c['image'];
    } 
    if($scheduledpost){
        $args['scheduled_publish_time'] = $timetopost;
        $args['published'] = 0 ;
    }

    try{                           
        $link = $facebook->api('/'.$pageid.'/feed','POST',$args);
        if( is_array( $link ) && !empty( $link['id'] ) ){
            ///photo posted, make comment with link
            if(isset($_POST['docomment']) && $_POST['docomment'] == 'yes'){
                $commentmessage = 'Found at '.$_POST['comment'];
                try{
                    $comment = $facebook ->api('/'.$link['id'].'/comments', 
                        'post', 
                        array(
                            'access_token' => $accesstoken,
                            'message' => $commentmessage,
                        )
                    );
                } catch (FacebookApiException $e){
                    echo '<h2>Had an error updating the comment '.$e->getMessage();
                }
            }

        }
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        echo "<h2>Error</h2>can't post link.<script>setTimeout(\"self.close();\",2500);</script>";
        exit;
    }
```

**update**

I ended up sending the image to facebook as a nostory and then get the source from the info and use that as the src for the link

```
if(isset($c['image'])){

        $targs = array(
           'published'=> 0,
           'no_story' => 0,
           'access_token' => $accesstoken,
           'image'=>$c['image']  
        );
        //try temporary photo
        $picture = $facebook->api($pageid . '/photos', 'post', $targs);
        if($picture){
            // get info about picture and set src to source 
            $picinfo = $facebook->api($picture['id']);
            $args['picture'] = $picinfo['source'];
            $c['src'] = $args['picture'];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where in your code does `$c['src']` get a value assigned?

Comment: that is in another part that isn't shown, this isn't meant to duplicate the application as that is not possible here, everything works without specifying 'thumbnail' but the error shows once it has been added to the list of args. the uploaded file in $_FILES['file'] works fine for a photo post but not for a link